# Sequence of integers using While loop

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I was given an exercise:

> Write and run a program that reads a sequence of integers until a negative integer is entered, then prints the sum of the positive even and positive odd integers. Use a While Loop.

Basically the user have infinite amount to enter integers and it will only stop if he entered a negative integers and it will display all the number of Even and Odd.

I tried my best to do it by myself without asking for help, but now I'm stuck.  Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    int odds =0;
    int evens =0;
    cout<<"Enter Positive integers.  \n\t:";
    cin>>n;
    while (n>0) {
        switch (n%2) {
        case 0:
            evens++;
            break;
        case 1:
            odds++;
        }

    }
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"the number of odds: "<<odds<<endl;
    cout<<"the number of evens: "<<evens<<endl;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @Notan Deward  For this assignment when you need to keep entered values I would suggest to use std::forward_list as a container.:)

Comment: First off, really take above advice and learn to use debugger, would be much faster to debug this than write question on SO. Secondly, you are reading `n` only once. Make sure to add another `cin>>n` at the end of your `while`. Oh and assignement is to print SUM not NUMBER of evens and odds, so switch `evens++` to `evens+=n` and `odds++` to `odds+=n`

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation @NathanOliver i will read that guide..

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota thank you for the hint but now i need to find out how to display . but thank you

Comment: @NathanOliver do you believe that by answering this type of questions is a little bit counterintuitive ? (I am talking about myself because I answered..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    int odds = 0;
    int evens = 0;

    while(cin >> n) {
        if(n < 0) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            if((n % 2) == 0) {
                ++odds;
            }
            else {
                ++evens;
            }
        }
    }
    cout  << "the number of odds: "<< odds << endl;
    cout  << "the number of evens: "<< evens << endl;
}
```

I wrote this code as simple as possible so you can understand what is going on. The `while(cin >> n)` keeps reading values(it will terminate if an `EOF` flag  is set). Then the program checks if the number is negative and exits the for loop, otherwise it calculates if the number is `odd` or `even`. You can experiment with this code by adding switch statements instead of ifs.

Comment: Please do not just give people the answer to their homework.  Learning how to debug and fix it is much better(you know the whole give a man a fish/teach a man to fish debate).  Also the check for negatives can be done in the while loop condition which gets rid of a branch.  On the plus side it does not actually do what the OP needs so there is that.

Comment: wow this is more simple than mine Thank you so much!! i will surely study this code and add some experiments..

Comment: @NathanOliver wow you answered the same time I was making the same question. Thanks for the feedback, I was actually thinking the same and felt bad for a moment. That's why I asked in the first place.

Comment: sorry for asking the solution. I've been doing this program for the last 3 hours at home and i don't really what to do.

Comment: @NotanDeward you don't have to be sorry about it but NathanOliver is right. I shouldn't have answered you the question but rather provide some guidance through the comments. That being said(because I already gave you the answer) you should study the code. Try to modify the while statement so it can check at the same time if the number is negative or not.  And please give a look at the link Nathan gave you. It should be a valuable tool.

Comment: Okay thank you so much. I am already doing some modification on your codes.

Comment: @NotanDeward that's good to hear. As a graduate student(I am getting my cs degree this September) I would suggest you not to post questions on stackoverflow unless its very important. You have to struggle a lot if before you become a good programmer.Since you mentioned you are a freshman you should study a lot. You will become better. You are there to a degree and from there make a career. :)